# scanner.close() Does not work when I use try/finally

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner, try-catch-finally

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class userInput
{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            int age = scanner.nextInt(); 
            scanner.nextLine();
            String text = scanner.nextLine();
        
            System.out.println(name + "\n" + age + "\n" + text);
            //scanner.close(); //it works here
        } 
    
        finally{
            scanner.close(); // does not work here"scanner cannot be resolvedJava(570425394)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define scanner before "try", so it's ok, now this is your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class userInput { 

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
             String name = scanner.nextLine();
             int age = scanner.nextInt(); 
             scanner.nextLine();
             String text = scanner.nextLine();

             System.out.println(name + "\n" + age + "\n" + text);
        } 

        finally {
             scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```